# What is the recent most important discovery and study about magnets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I believe that magnetism is a very powerful tool to do various things.It can make amazing machines.What is the recent most important piece of study that has been done of magnetism.

The study that can help us better understand the Magnetic Field which has been a mystery since long.

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a primarily opinion-based list question.

Comment: @qmechanic and i have come here for the expert opinions.
i would be glad to know whats yours.

Comment: Sohaib, you need to be more specific, even for an opinion. The most important "recent" event for magnetism itself was Ironside's conversion of Maxwell's equations into their current form, which pretty much closed the book on _how_ magnetism works. Given that, is your question about new magnetic materials, or new designs, or what? You might even want to consider asking over at Chemistry SE if your real question is about interesting events in magnetic materials.

Answer (score 3):

From a practical point of view, the development of [Iron Nitride magnets](http://license.umn.edu/technologies/20120016_iron-nitride-permanent-magnet-alternative-to-rare-earth-and-neodymium-magnets) which are potentially more powerful than NeFeB, and of course do not need rare earthe elements